# Scope of a variable in java

Tags: java, variables, scope, initialization, declaration

[the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7R6a.jpg)
As per variable scope m (not initialized) shouldn't be having a value in it, and that's correct, im getting an error for it but when you initialize a variable and then use it in the conditional construct inside the iterative construct, it can get any value you provide it with.

why is that? shouldn't the variable scope remain the same regardless of its initialization?

basically if i declare int a; and give it a value inside an if condition which is inside a for loop it doesn't get the value and remains un-initialized, but if initialize it, int a=0; and then give it any value inside an if condition which is inside a for loop, it does get the value i give it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and error message as text, not an image.

Comment: As for the question... This has exactly *nothing* to do with scope.  The compiler is not going to examine your logic and determine if any given variable *will be* initialized.  Whether or not a condition is logically guaranteed to be true doesn't matter.  The compiler sees it as a condition and tells you that the operation within that condition *might not* happen.  The takeaway here is that, if you have a logical condition that you know will always be true under all circumstances, then refactor the code to remove the unnecessary condition.

Comment: Variable scope doesn't change depending on how you initialize your variable and has nothing to do with your error. Your error is simply that the compiler cannot guarantee that any possible path your code can take will lead to the variable being initialized because you only initialize it in conditional blocks that might not be reached at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to recommend the following article to you here you can find examples as well:

[https://www.baeldung.com/java-error-variable-initialized#:~:text=This%20error%20occurs%20only%20for,the%20use%20of%20uninitialized%20variables](https://www.baeldung.com/java-error-variable-initialized#:%7E:text=This%20error%20occurs%20only%20for,the%20use%20of%20uninitialized%20variables).

Summary of the article:
If we declare a local variable without an initial value, we’ll get an error. This error occurs only for local variables, since Java automatically initializes the instance variables at compile time (it sets 0 for integers, false for boolean, etc.). However, local variables need a default value because the Java compiler doesn’t allow the use of uninitialized variables.

I hope it helps

Comment: That article is too simplistic. Local variables must be initialized before use. This means that if they are not used, they don't have to be initialized. For example, if they are only used in an inner block, they only have to be initialized in that inner block. Also, they don't have to be initialized in the same statement as their declaration. They can be initialized, for example, after declaration, e.g. `int n; if (cond) n = 1; else n = 2;` The linked article doesn't seem to make this very clear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).